# Python: Convert SELECT query list to dict

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, dictionary

Trying convert to dict this SELECT Query, because I have duplicate names.

```
def getcity():
 conn = databaseConnection()
 cur = conn.cursor()
 conn.set_client_encoding('LATIN1')
 cur.execute("SELECT codcity, name FROM cities")
 rows = cur.fetchall()
 cities= [dict(row) for row in rows]  
 return cities
```

Resulting: `TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence`

Duplicate examples:

```
Id - 132 | Name: New York
Id - 24 | Name: NEW York
```

I do not have sure, but using dict, is the best way to handle with duplicate case. Final result that I desire:

```
'New York': { 
'id-1': 132,
'id-2': 24 }
```

**print(rows[0])**

```
(338, u'')
None
```

UPDATE: 
output (slightly altered rows):

```
<type 'list'>
[(u'Jam', [314]),
 (u'Arthur Cat', [527]),
 (u'Bel', [406]),
 (u'Bel of Taq', [415]),
 (u'Good Luck', [420]),
 (u'GOOD LUCK', [467]),
 (u'Bc do Toto', [407]),
 (u'Caera', [322]),
 (u'Caira S\xe3o George', [506]),
 (u'Grand Good', [373]),
```

Comment: show us what print(rows[0]) prints

Comment: Is that what you want to see?

Comment: Where do `id-1` and `id-2` come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` in the query to get all the codes for a city together as a comma-delimited string, then split it up in Python to create a list.

```
 cur.execute("SELECT name, ARRAY_AGG(codcity) FROM cities GROUP BY name")
 rows = cur.fetchall()
 cities = {}
 for row in rows:
    cities[row[0]] = [int(code) for code in row[1].split(',')]
```

This will put the codes in a list, not a dictionary, which is probably better than making up dictionary keys like `id-1`, `id-2`, etc., e.g.

```
'New York': [132, 24]
```

Comment: This is great. The SELECT is working I just changed GROUP_CONCAT to array_agg, because I'm using postgresql. But this error is showing: [int(code) for code in row[1].split(',')]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: What does `print(rows[0])` show? `row[1]` should be a string like `'132,24'`, I don't know why it's a list.

Comment: both are list type.. does SELECT query always return a list? How to proceed?

Comment: `fetchall()` is supposed to return a list of tuples. Each column of the result should be a string in the tuple.

Comment: Why have you accepted the answer if it doesn't actually work?

Comment: Because this array_agg was a big help... But if you have any solution for this list, I'm listening you :)

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(rows)` in the question?

Answer (score 2):

dict expects a list of tuples. So you just have to provide the `rows` variable

```
cities= dict(rows)
```

From pythons documentation:

> The dict() constructor builds dictionaries directly from sequences of key-value pairs

Here is an example:

```
>>> rows = [(1,"12"), (2,"abc"), (3,"random")]
>>> dict(rows)
{1: '12', 2: 'abc', 3: 'random'}
```

Comment: Look at his desired output. The city name should be the key, and the value should be all the codes for that city.

Comment: True that. I did not notice the expected output. The way the code was written made me believe it was just the dict he wanted.

Comment: I am using sqlite3 with python3. When I use `rows=cursor.fecthall()` followed by `data = dict(rows)` I get following error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required